# Why do we have to integrate power to get the function of the work?

Tags: classical-mechanics

Why do I have to integrate the function of the power to get the function of the work if both the force which is applied to the object and the displacement are changing?

Both the force and the displacement are function of time
And the textbook says that I can't use this formula

W = F . s without giving any details.

Why can't I just manipulate force and displacement to get the work function?

Comment: Suppose you meet a stranger and want to explain the question to him. What are the details needed to explain your question? Put in all those details in this question.

Comment: Well, I don't study mechanics in English right now as I'm still in high school so I'm not sure how to translate such a problem from Arabic to English. Do I need to reference anything from wiki? Like the definition of the power or anything?

Comment: what object are u talking bout? how is force applied? how is it changing? is this an object in space or an object in a field?

Comment: Note that power is Energy per unit time. If you integrate it w.r.t time you will get the amount of work done in a time interval.

Comment: Ty, I have corrected the question. I wasn't fully aware of what I'm typing sorry. Is it now clear though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could think about why you need to integrate velocity to get position if it is changing with time.  The idea is the same.  $W=Fs$ works when the force is constant because it is the same as the integral.  So does $s=vt$ when the velocity is constant.

Comment: Thank you. it does make sense now. Even though i'm not fully satisfied with answer but I got that